# Need Array formula to multiple match different column with different rows and get result in EXCEL 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have attach the excel file [image]

Need Array formula to multiple match different column with different rows and get result in EXCEL 2007

As you can refer to the picture I want to check Year between 2000 and 2010 along with Month, Day & Type common in all 11 rows i.e. 1, 1 & A

I need to check total 11 Rows having all same criteria from `ROW 2 Y=2000, ROW 2 M=1, ROW 2 D=1, ROW 2 TYPE=A, Y=2001,CELL 249 M=1, ROW 249 D=1, ROW 249 TYPE=A, ........ROW 2480 Y=2010, ROW 2480 M =1, ROW 2480 D=1, ROW 2480 TYPE=A .....IF all these are satisfied only then Mark "X" Else ""`

Comment: Sorry to say, this question just doesn't make sense. What's the situation where you don't need "X", it's if always day=1 month =1 and type =A regardless of year ? Why do you need array formula?

Comment: Why do you need an array formula?  Why do you need to check the year?

Comment: If you see in the image, in column D there are two values "A" AND "B" now what I want in Sell E2 is , that suppose in Year 2000 and in Month 1 and Day 1 and Column D = "A" , Like wise if all these conditions are Ture till Year 2010 only Then it displays "X" else it should leave blank

Comment: I need array formula coz, if then I Change from M=1 Day=1 to M=1 and Day=15

Comment: @SirajMultani,, please click this link [edit] & modify the criteria (that U need all 11 rows to test),, and please delete the New Question since it will be treated like DUPLICATE post and would attract down vote too !! –

Comment: @SirajMultani,, now check my post I've posted new formula !!

Answer (score 1):

*Even a non array `IF` logical formula can solve the issue.*

[image]

- Formula in cell `E46`:

  ```
    =IF(AND(A46>=2000,A46<=2099,B46=1,C46=1,D46="A"),"X","")
  ```

**N.B.**

- The first part `IF(AND(A46>=2000,A46<=2099` checks year falls between `99` years of span, which would be at the maximum possible.
- Since rest criteria are common `Month`, `Day` & `Type` should `1`, `1` and `A`, then the `IF` combined with `AND` solves the issue.

---

**Edited:**

*I've edited the post since OP's need is to check all 11 Rows for the said criteria.*

- An array (CSE) formula in any required cell:

  ```
   {=IF(AND(A$46:A$57>=2000,A$46:A$57<=2002,B$46:B$57=1,C$46:C$57=1,D$46:D$57="A"),"X","No Match")}
  ```
- Finish the formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**
- Using current data (shared by OP ) this will return `No Match`.
- But with my sample data it return `X` since row `51` meets all criteria.

---

**Note:** *this may works as non array formula also, but as precaution better use as an array (CSE) formula.*

*Adjust year's value & cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Please write your concern also that Y this has been down voted!!

Comment: your formula will only check the Value in 1 row, but I need to check total 11 Rows having all same cireteria from ROW 2 Y=2000, ROW 2 M=1, ROW 2 D=1, ROW 2 TYPE=A, Y=2001,CELL 249 M=1, ROW 249 D=1, ROW 249 TYPE=A, ........ROW 2480 Y=2010, ROW 2480 M =1, ROW 2480 D=1, ROW 2480 TYPE=A .....IF all these are satisfied only then Mark "X" Else ""

Comment: @SirajMultani you comment to this answer shows your question needs updating as it is not clear. The answer provided by Rajesh does answer your question as asked. You need to make it clear you need the search result to show an X if and only if ALL the dates meet your requirement.

Comment: @SirajMultani,, I've exactly answered as your post reflects (even the modified version is as similar as provious),, if you want to check Year between 2000 and 2010 along with `Month`, `Day` & `Type` common in all 11 rows i.e. `1`, `1` & `A` the better [EDit] your post and make it clear,, you have no idea how much time we are investing to create proper answer and every day twist in the question simply spoils our efforts!!

Comment: Dear Rajesh, we really appriciate the effort you experts contribute to this site. Trust me for us to be on this site is like 1 stop solution. Thank you so much Mr Rajesh.

Comment: I will take your advise and revised my post.

Comment: Mr Rajesh, I have edit the original post of this thread as per your sujjestion